# Is it possible to make Opera not to run any plugin before I'll click on it?

Tags: browser, plugins, opera

I want to prohibit opera 11 browser from running plugins (like flash and java) before I will click on plugin content. E.g. When I go to http://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes it does run my flash plugin and my java plugin, but I want to prohibit this. If there will be a Flash or Java object I will click on it to run plugin.

My settings are Preferences -> Advanced -> Content -> Enable Plugins "Yes"; Enable plugins on demand "Yes"

But panopticlick still can run my java and my flash without asking me. Also, some sites have a lot of flash banners and only minor part (~1/3) are stopped in "Click to play" and most are activated without any clicks.

Is it possible?

The Chrome browser can this AFAIK. but I want to do same with opera///

Comment: I can also accept solution with some js-solution, which is compatible with opera or extension for opera.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Flashblock User Javascript for Opera instead: http://my.opera.com/Lex1/blog/flashblock-for-opera-9

Description from website:

> Flashblock is an addition for the Opera that blocks all Flash,
> Silverlight and Java content from loading. It then leaves placeholders
> on the webpage that allow you to click to download and then view the
> Flash content.

---

> My settings are Preferences -> Advanced -> Content -> Enable Plugins "Yes"; Enable plugins on demand "Yes"
>
> panopticlick still can run my java and my flash without asking me. Also, some sites have a lot of flash banners and only minor part (~1/3) are stopped in "Click to play" and most are activated without any clicks.

I believe this is an Opera bug.

See these Opera forum posts reporting the same thing:

http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=928161
http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1010982
http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=992952
http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=951882
http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1048122
http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1026992

Comment: may be it is a feature? Can I fully turn of all flash with any opera extension?

Comment: @sgsadg I edited my answer to suggest another method. It's a User Javascript-Flashblock for Opera.